# Pop up month calendar's all days are disabled in angularx - flatpickr

Tags: angular, date, flatpickr

I am using 'angularx-flatpickr' to select date in angular form. When I clicked the input area and then pop up month view appear but all dates are disabled.

In my html file,

```
    <input 
          type="text"
          mwlFlatpickr
          [(ngModel)]="enddate"
          [altInput]="true"
          [convertModelValue]="true"
          altFormat = "F j,Y"
          dateFormat= "Y-m-d"
          class="form-control"
          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          (ngModelChange)="changeDate($event)">
```

I import this `import { FlatpickrModule } from 'angularx-flatpickr';` to my app.module.ts and in my import array  `FlatpickrModule.forRoot()`.
My angular cli version is `7.2.1`.

This is the output,
[image]
`

How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downgrading the **flatpickr** version.
This worked for me. I am currently using the v4.6.6 of flatpickr

Comment: Thank you after change the flatpicker version to downgrade its works fine.

Comment: That didn't work for me. 
I am using enable:[function(date)] and doing some manipulations in it...

Comment: Whenever I click on next month then it starts showing the days.. otherwise by default the dates are disabled

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue. One workaround was to explicitly enable a date range:

```
public datePickerOptions : FlatpickrDefaultsInterface = {
    allowInput : true,
    enableTime : true,
    mode : 'single',
    dateFormat : "Y-m-d H:i",
    // this:
    enable : [{from : new Date(0, 1), to : new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + 200, 12)}]
  }
```

```html
<input class="form-control"
             name="start" formControlName="start" mwlFlatpickr
             [options]="datePickerOptions">
```